# Angular 8 - Route external url

Tags: angular

I have the following route that returns a token

```
if (!this.session.token) {
let urlToken= 'https://www.url-system.com.br//auth&redirect_uri=http://8000/api/res-token';
let route = this.router.navigateByUrl(urlToken);
}
```

When I try to return the token from the url the application returns the error:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:'
```

How can I make the redirect without opening the browser page just returning the response of this request?

I've tried using get and observable and I haven't had success.

Comment: What response you will get upon successful call the endpoint?

Comment: The return redirect to http://localhost:8080/acess-token?my-code=MDk2MzYzOA==
But I would like to retrieve the url into a variable for me to manipulate.

Comment: So when you call `https://www.url-system.com.br/auth&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/api/res-token`. Your external server knows where to redirect you back depends on what you pass in `redirect_uri` right?  So It should redirect you to  `http://localhost:8000/api/res-token?my-code=MDk2MzYzOA==` with token right? On which basis your external server decides to redirect you to ` localhost:8080/acess-token?my-code=MDk2MzYzOA==` then?

Comment: Yes it's right. However, it redirects in the browser itself. As if it were a normal page.
What would you like to do and that when redirected not open the page but saved in a variable so you can manipulate.

Comment: Let's say we have external URL as `https://www.url-system.com.br/auth&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/api/res-token` where he will give us token at `http://localhost:8000/api/res-token?token=***`.

Comment: We will create component named res-token. Add it in routing with path `api/res-token`. So whenever he will redirect back we can get it's token from uri in this res-token component

Comment: created the route with my component
HomeComponent
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'token', component: HomeComponent},
];
Only it is in infinite looping.

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-apm3hk

Answer (score 0):

The `Router` can only be used with the routes you register in your application. Try using the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for navigating to an external url:

```
location.assign(urlToken); // or
location = urlToken;
```

Comment: I tested it and it keeps redirecting to the page localhost:8080
What would you like and when to enter the login and password on the page record the data in a variable